# Is there any way to "Allow Guest Account to log in to this computer" via the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mountain-lion, guest-account

How to enable “Allow Guests to log in to this computer” option on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) via command line?

Comment: There are quite a few things going on in the background when you tick the box. Not easy two wrap this all up in one or two lines of code. Is there a specific reason you need to do this via command line?

Comment: @slhck Yes, I am planning on automating the installation of my workstation. How about with Apple Script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option "Allow guests to log in to this computer" is stored as "GuestEnabled" key in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist`

You can change it by using `defaults` command with root permission, tested on MountainLion 10.8.4

#### Read

```
sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow GuestEnabled
#1 -> Enabled, 0 -> Disabled
```

#### Write

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow GuestEnabled -bool YES|NO
```

Comment: This does not work on 10.14.x for devices that have never had the Guest account previously enabled. I posted a question in regards to this and 10.14 on Ask Different at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346088/enable-guest-user-in-10-14-x-via-the-command-line-without-a-mdm